# Redirect after animation in Jquery

Tags: jquery, redirect

I have this code:

```
setTimeout(function() {  
  $('#squareone').animate({top: '-760px'},1000);
 }, 22200

 );
```

This animates the `#squareone`div. The problem I wanted to solve is to redirect after the animation is done.How can I do this? 
I know the redirect works like this `window.location.href = "/home.html"`

Thanks!

Comment: Try `window.location.href=<url_to_redirect>`

Answer (score 2):

Use animate callback function:

```
$('#squareone').animate({
    top: '-760px'
}, 1000, function () {
    window.location.href = "myuri"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)'s complete callback to place your redirection logic.

```
$('#squareone')
         .animate({top: '-760px'}, 
           1000, 
           function(){
               //redirect here
              window.location.href=myredirectionuri;
   });
```